# Location listener is always returning the googpleplex latitude and longitude

Tags: android

I'm trying to implement a locationListener in my app but somehow onLocationChanged always gives the location of googleplex instead of my virtual device "location"

```
  if(location == null){
                Log.i("YEH", "WE MAY HAVE A PROBLEM  ");
            }
            Intent  intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MapsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("Latitude", location.getLatitude());
            intent.putExtra("Longitude",location.getLongitude());
            Log.i("LatLong", "LAt: " + location.getLatitude() + "LONG" + location.getLongitude());
            startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }
    };
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >=  23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
        } else {
            locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,locationListener,null);
        }
    } else {
        locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,locationListener,null);
    }
```

Comment: Have you set the lat and long manually in yout virtual device?

Comment: yep, I've used set the latitude and longitude manually and I verified that the coordinates are good

Comment: Have you tried on a physical device?

Comment: I've just tried my app in a real device... and it works.... also it seems that I only have a problem when I use the network provider on my virtual device